# Can I compare two different page's stats in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I remember a very old Google Analytics has a feature that can let you compare some particular page's stats with the whole site's.

For instance, I have a website: `website.com`

And I have 3 pages:

```
website.com/index.html
website.com/contact.html
website.com/about.html
```

I want to compare the `page views` or `unique visitors` of those pages in a specified time range. What should I do?

Also I want to compare some page's stats with the whole site's, for example:

`PV for index.html` VS `PV for the 3 pages`.

Thanks for any kind of tips!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a segment that includes the three pages (create new segment->condition->page->matches regex->index.html|contact.html|about.html) and do a side-by-side comparison with the default "All visits" segment.

Comment: thanks, but where to find the "create new segment" button (or link)?

Comment: ok, i found it here: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/new-google-analytics-advanced-segments/

Comment: Still don't know how to do the `side-by-side` comparison. Besides, I want to put all graphs in one so that it can be very convenient to see the comparison, is that possible?

Comment: If you select more than one segment (works with up to 4) you will get a side-by-side (or rather one-below-the-other) comparison of the segments.

Comment: Would you please let me know how can I select more than one segment?

Comment: Finally found it in updated UI of analytics, it's "Add Segment" semi-transparent plank -> "+ New Segment" red button.

Comment: @Brock is it possible to set Secondary Y Axis for a new added segment?