# Compare 2 pages (old/new) in 2 different timeframes in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

On site.com I've two products: site.com/product-1 (old product) and site.com/product-2 (new product)

On these two pages, I have to compare their
•   page visits
•   users
•   time spent on page 
•   bounce rate 
•   etc

in a different timeframe: same period last year and this year.

I already had a look at [Can I compare two different page's stats in Google Analytics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20931378/can-i-compare-two-different-pages-stats-in-google-analytics) but it's not what I'm looking for.

Thanks for any kind of suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two parts to your question, one part is about how to compare two different timeframes, the other is how to get a report with page visits, users, time spent on page, bounce rate, etc. Maybe a third is about filters.

**Comparing stats in two different periods**
In the date selection, there is a "Compare to" checkbox, check that and select the periods that you want to compare, like so (I'm comparing 2017 to 2016):
[image]

**Creating a custom report**
[Here's a guide on how to get the dimensions and metrics that you want](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en). In your case, I would select the "Page" dimension and select the metrics that you want to include (avg. time on page, pageviews, users, bounce rate, etc). Make sure the report type is "Explorer"

After you finish creating the report, you'll see a list of all the pages on your site with the metrics you've selected. Click on the "advanced" link beside the "search" to do some advanced filtering. Add a "Matchin RegExp" filter like so (the "|" means Or):
[image]

When you apply the filter, you should see only those two product pages listed, if not, look at your regex to make sure they're specific enough. [Here is a quickstart](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) if you're not familiar.

When you have done that, use the "compare to" period to select the periods you want to compare.

Then when you're done, there should be checkboxes beside the product pages you want to compare, check those and click on "Plot Rows" at the top and you should see the two pages plotted in the graph above as well.

[image]